# Hide/Mask Confidential Data In Spring REST Response

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-data-rest

I am creating a rest service using Spring REST+Spring Security. In few services I need to Hide/Mask data in response.

For example, I don't want anybody to see a user's password. So the password field should be empty or should not be present in response. I am using same DTO in request and list response. That's why could not remove attribute from DTO.

Similarly, account number should be masked as `xxx-xxx-xxx-123`.

Is there any way in spring to achieve this? Or any common solution that could be applied on all `entities/controller` when `ResponseEntity` is returned (like `Interceptor`)?

Comment: Put `@JsonIgnore` on the field / property.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you could use either @JsonIgnore, as already suggested, or projections. If you need more controle over response, you could implement your own Serializers as well.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to mask only selected field, during logging and keep other field values as is. you can try this.

https://github.com/senthilaru/sp-util

```html
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.immibytes</groupId>
    <artifactId>sp-utils</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```